# Null param in C# action when called from Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm calling a C# action method (Mvc.Controller) from AngularJS and the param is null in the action. Why?

Here's the Angular call:

```
return $http.get(
                "AdvancedSearch/SearchUsers",
                {
                    params: {
                        search: {
                            SearchTerms: searchTerms,
                            Markets: markets,
                            Roles: roles,
                            Capabilities: capabilities,
                            Groups: groups,
                            Industries: experience,
                            Skills: skills,
                            Technologies: technologies,
                            Certifications: certification
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
```

Here's the C# view model:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string SearchTerms { get; set; }
    public List<string> Markets { get; set; }
    public List<int> Roles { get; set; }
    public List<string> Capabilities { get; set; }
    public List<string> Groups { get; set; }
    public List<int> Industries { get; set; }
    public List<int> Skills { get; set; }
    public List<int> Technologies { get; set; }
    public List<string> Certifications { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the action method signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult SearchUsers(SearchViewModel search) // <- this is null
```

Here's the request URL, decoded:

```
https://localhost:44300/AdvancedSearch/SearchUsers?search={"SearchTerms":"","Markets":["Boise"],"Roles":[],"Capabilities":[],"Groups":[],"Industries":[],"Skills":[],"Technologies":[],"Certifications":[]}
```

The call worked fine before I converted it from using separate params to using a single view model.

**UPDATE**: Trying to pass as single string param instead.

Here's the Angular call:

```
return $http.get(
                "AdvancedSearch/SearchUsers",
                {
                    params: JSON.stringify({
                        jsonSearchData: {
                            SearchTerms: searchTerms,
                            Markets: markets,
                            Roles: roles,
                            Capabilities: capabilities,
                            Groups: groups,
                            Industries: experience,
                            Skills: skills,
                            Technologies: technologies,
                            Certifications: certifications
                        }
                    })
                }
            );
```

Here's the new C# method signature:

```
public JsonResult SearchUsers(string jsonSearchData) // still coming over null
```

Comment: is it httppost or GET?

Comment: Added that detail to the question.

Comment: You have to pass the parameters as a query string, not json. The only way around that is to provide a custom model binder that deserializes the json to an object and assigns it to the model. (*I assume you are using MVC and not Web API*)

Comment: are you using angular 4 ?I mentioned JSON.stringyfy because you can accept it as string in your action method and then deserialize it using JSON.NET

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET MVC. Added that detail to the question. I thought MVC did basic model binding automatically.

Comment: You could also change the signature to `SearchUsers(string search)` and deserialize in the method from json. A custom model binder would be cleaner though.

Comment: @birdus it would work in case of POST but in multiple get params you have to use querystring and use multiple params in your action method argments , a better way will be send them as serialized json as string to action method.

Comment: `I thought MVC did basic model binding automatically` <= not from json when the data is passed in the URL. It would work if it were passed in the message body and the action type was Post or Put but that would be misleading if this is a public facing api.

Comment: So, trying to pass a single string (changed param in action to one string), it still comes over as null. I tried with and without using JSON.stringify() in Angular. Adding code to question.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for your help with this. I learned a few things from your input and, after discussing with a co-worker, decided to go with POST as the best solution.

Comment: @Niladri Thanks for your help and knowledge. I decided to go with POST.

Comment: Have you tried decorating the C# parameter with `[FromBody]` (for POST) or `[FromUri]` (for GET) to see if the parameters populate that way? I.E. `public JsonResult SearchUsers([FromUri] SearchViewModel search)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return $http.get(
                "AdvancedSearch/SearchUsers",
                {
                    params: {
                        //search: {
                            SearchTerms: searchTerms,
                            Markets: markets,
                            Roles: roles,
                            Capabilities: capabilities,
                            Groups: groups,
                            Industries: experience,
                            Skills: skills,
                            Technologies: technologies,
                            Certifications: certification
                        //}
                    }
                }
            );
```

Comment: Doing it that way the C# object is NOT null, but all of its properties ARE null, and they shouldn't be. Closer!